# what is the difference between the following to coding in VHDL to update registers?

Tags: styles, vhdl

Could I ask what is the difference between the following two coding styles? For the first one I read from XILINX sample code. For the second, I read it from a book teaching VHDL.

```
1. signal: register std_logic；
   signal: output std_logic;
   process (clk)
   begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      register <= outside_signal ; 
    end if;
   end process;

   output <= register;

2. signal: register_reg    std_logic;
   signal: register_next   std_logic;
   signal: output std_logic;
   process (clk)
   begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      register_reg <= register_next; 
    end if;
   end process;
   register_next<=outside_signal;
   output <= register_reg;
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious difference is that an intermediate signal register_next is declared and driven by the outside_signal signal, instead of just using the outside_signal directly in the process.

The simple answer is that there is no functional difference.  (Complex answer is that the `register_next<=outside_signal` delays the signal by a delta delay (not actual time delay), but this delta delay is typically not visible so don't worry about it if you don't understand that concept.)

From a coding style point of view, the "renaming" of of a signal through the `register_next<=outside_signal` construction should be avoided, since it is confusing to read code where signals with the same functional behavior and same origin are called by different names.

Also, from a coding style point of view I would suggest that the name of the signal driven by the clocked process, and the name of the output, have some defined similarity.  For this I would suggest that the output is called for example result_o, and the internal signal that is updated by the process is then called result.  The internal intermediate signal is required by VHDL-2002 if the result is to be read in the module, and the output port is then assigned with `result_o <= result`.  When the code is read, is the thereby easier to understand that the result_o and result are related.  Thus code:

```
process (clk)
begin
 if rising_edge(clk) then
   result <= outside_signal;
 end if;
end process;
result_o <= result;
```

Btw. "register" is reserved VHDL keyword, so you can't use that as signal identifier.

Comment: I am not sure if you are correct. In ETHZ, the IC research group recommends the second way.

Comment: What do you mean by "the second way" ?  Does ETHZ have a public available VHDL style guide; if there are some additional thoughts on this I would like to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Both seems quite funky examples: the first example uses a [reserved word](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/reserved.html), the second example uses lots of intermediate signals (maybe there is a reason though).

Generally stuff like `my_output <= my_register;` after a process is used to pull out of the device (that is why it is called my_output) an internal signal (that is why it is called my_register) that you maybe used as counter or maybe to pull out just one bit of a std_logic_vector of an input.

See page 161 and 162 of [this](http://books.google.es/books?id=g-TBaAyAwQ4C&lpg=PA89&pg=PA161#v=onepage&q&f=false) for few simple examples.